# What do the letters F T S R and E mean in Sendmail milter?

Tags: sendmail

I see on sendmail.mc milters lines like this:

```
Xclamantivirus, S=local:/var/run/clamav-milter/clamav.sock,F=T,T=S:4m;R:4m;E:4m
```

I know what is a local socket.
But what do the letters F T S R and E mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All but "E:" is explained in *[Scanning e-mail for virusses with ClamAV and Sendmail](http://www.bilbos-stekkie.com/clamav/index.php?action=1)* by Peter Kaagman.  Reformatting and fixing a few typos:

> **`S=`**`local:/var/run/clamav/clmilter.sock` of course is the socket created by clamav-milter
>
> **`F=`** tells Sendmail what to do if the filter fail, blank means act as if there is no filter. You could use "R" for reject or "T" for temporary fail.
>
> **`T=`** determines timeouts:
>
> **`S:4m`** a timeout of 4 minutes for sending to the filter
>
> **`R:4m`** a timeout of 4 minutes for receiving from the filter

Answer (score 0):

Found explanation [here](http://www.bilbos-stekkie.com/clamav/index.php?action=1) for F T S R 
and [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.networkcomm/mail_filterconfigs.htm) for E

```
S=local:/var/run/clamav/clmilter.sock offcourse is the socket created by clamav-milter

F= tells Sendmail what to do if the filter fail, blank means act as if there is no filter. You could use "R" for reject or "T" for temporary fail.

T= determens timeouts:

E= Overall timeout between sending end-of-message notices to the filter and waiting for the final acknowledgement. 

R= a timeout of "n" minutes for receiving from the filter
```

Comment: Peter Kaagman doesn't document "E:".

Comment: Edited,IBM explain